# Difference among Android's emulator command variations

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, android-sdk-tools

There're several `emulator` binary variations residing in the Android SDK's `/tools` folder but I don't find any documentation on their differences (e.g. when to which one).

[image: screenshot of different emulator command variations]

Android SDK version is 24.4.1, on CentOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you don't need to care about this, a default emulator will be chosen for you (first binary). Each binary represents one of the supported architectures. The last five are the 32-bit emulators.

[Android emulator is based on QEMU](https://www.linaro.org/blog/core-dump/running-64bit-android-l-qemu/)

> When the Android SDK was first made available to the world, Google
>   used QEMU as the basis for their Android emulator. They copied the
>   source code to a custom repository in the Android Open Source Project
>   (AOSP) and made a number of invasive modifications to QEMU.
>   Specifically, they added emulation of a specific board called goldfish
>   for the purposes of emulating an Android phone.
>
> Every build of Android targets a specific hardware platform, and the
>   emulated goldfish platform is no different. A number of specific
>   emulator features are enabled in both the Android kernel and Android
>   userspace environment when run in an emulated environment. These
>   features allow a smooth and complete user experience resembling using
>   a real Android device, on laptop and desktop workstations.
>
> The Android emulator provides Android application developers with a
>   convenient development environment and allows developers to develop
>   and test applications on devices which they do not have physical
>   access to. With the introduction of the ARMv8-A architecture and
>   Android support for 64-bit ARM platforms, this need is more important
>   than ever because it allows developers to begin adapting their
>   applications to an ARM 64-bit based mobile ecosystem prior to hardware
>   being available.

You can use the default emulator [like here](https://travis-ci.org/ardock/android-topeka/jobs/152108993#L917) (or add QEMU options, but I never needed it, [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26539867/1009132)).

[image]

[image]

You also can force a 32-bit emulator:

[image]

[image]